# Button Onclick inside a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, onclick, repeater

I have created a repeater that gets 3 different values from a webbservice(Name, Surname and Number). Depending on if the Number I receive is 1 or 0 there are 2 buttons that are set Visible= true or false. (btnNumber0 and btnNumber1).

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptHB_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="rptHB_ItemCommand">     
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div>
            <h1 class="click">
                <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="lblSurname" runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Surname").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="lblNumber" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Numer").ToString() %>'></asp:Label>
            </h1>

            <div class="expand"> 
                <select id="optColor">
                    <option>Blue</option>
                    <option>Red</option>
                    <option>Yellow</option>                       
                    <option>Green</option>
                    <option>Black</option>
                </select>                  

                <asp:Button ID="btnNumber0" runat="server" Text="0"/>
                <asp:Button ID="btnNumber1" runat="server" Text="1"/>                            
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The thing i cant get to work is to make a onClick function to my 2 button. Inside the OnCick I want to take the Name and Color(optColor) from the Person I select and send it back to my webbservice. Do i have to use OnItemCommand, if so can you help me? Or is it another way you can do it?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GetInfo();
}

private void GetInfo()
{
    rpt1.DataSource = client.SendInfo();
    rpt1.DataBind();
}

private bool Getbutton(string ValueNumber)
{
    return ValueNumber == "0";
}

protected void rptHB_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    Label lblNewNumber = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblNumber");
    Label lblNewName = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblName");
    Button btnNewNumber0 = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("btnNumer0");
    Button btnNewNumber1 = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("btnNumber1");
    string Number = lblNewNumber.Text;
    btnNewNumber0.Visible = GetButton(Number);
    btnNewNumber1.Visible = !GetButton(Number);
 }

protected void rptHB_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    /* ??? */
}
```

Comment: Yes use OnItemCommand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If i understand you correctly you want to handle both button's click event and get a value of the name and color  of the Person of that `RepeaterItem`. You could use the same handler:

aspx:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnNumber0" OnClick="btn_Click" runat="server" Text="0"/>
<asp:Button ID="btnNumber1" OnClick="btn_Click" runat="server" Text="1"/>
```

codebehind:

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button) sender;
    RepeaterItem item = (RepeaterItem) btn.NamingContainer;
    Button btnNewNumber0 = (Button)item.FindControl("btnNumer0");
    Button btnNewNumber1 = (Button)item.FindControl("btnNumer1");
    bool btn0Clicked = btn == btnNewNumber0;
    btnNewNumber0.Visible = !btn0Clicked;
    btnNewNumber1.Visible = btn0Clicked;
    // now call your webservice, you have all you need here
    Label lblName = (Label) item.FindControl("lblName"); 
    Label lblSurname = (Label) item.FindControl("lblSurname"); 
    Label lblNumber = (Label) item.FindControl("lblNumber"); 
    DropDownList ddlColor = (DropDownList) item.FindControl("ddlColor");
    // now call your webservice, you get the color-selection via ddlColor.SelectedValue
}
```

Use also a `DropDownList` instead of a HTML `Select` if you want to access it on serverside.

Comment: Works exactly like I want! Thank you :)

Comment: Error "The name 'sender' does not exist in the current" 
(need change "source" in function signature to "sender")